# moment.isBetween() is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, moment-timezone, datejs

I am using moment (version "^2.25.3") library to check if the date is in between two dates.

I have to check, if araDate is in between two dates(startdate and endDate) or araDateMinusOne is in between the dates(startDate and endDate), but the condition here is startdate should be equal to araDateMinusOne(ie if a startdate is sep/03 and enddate is sep/04, it should not match).

Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong or why exactly is this happening?

```js
const obj = {
  _id: '614c2b941e06b7003024e1df',
  promotedtitles: [{ title: '1' }, { title: '2' }],
  startdate: '2021-09-04T00:00:00.000Z',
  enddate: '2021-09-04T00:00:00.000Z'
};

const camStartDate = moment(obj.startdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2021-09-04
const camEndDate = moment(obj.enddate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2021-09-04
const araDate = moment('2021-09-05T00:00:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2021-09-05
const araDateMinusOne = moment('2021-09-05T00:00:00.000Z').subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2021-09-04

console.log('check', moment(araDate).isBetween(camStartDate, camEndDate, undefined, '[]')); // false which is fine.
console.log('another check', moment(araDateMinusOne).isBetween(camStartDate, camEndDate, undefined, '[)')); // this is consoling false, which is incorrect

//I also have tried this as well and all the variations.

console.log('another check', moment(araDateMinusOne).isBetween(camStartDate, camEndDate, 'day', '[)'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: Latest version is 2.29.1

Comment: can't update the library. And according to docs isBetween should work in 2.9.0+.

Comment: @mplungjan Also not working in the latest one("^2.29.1",).

Comment: camStartDate and camEndDate are identical to araDateMinusOne.  So if you use any exclusion it will return false.

Comment: yes, exactly.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why it is returning false for checking the equal range and giving '[)', as a parameter is the enddate is taking priority here. And when it is checking endDate we are giving exclusion operator for that.

```
moment('2021-09-04').isBetween('2021-09-04', '2021-09-04', 'day', '[)'
```

The solution to this problem is to check the date is between two dates and if the startdate is equal to that araMinusOne date.

```
moment(araDateMinusOne).isBetween(camStartDate, camEndDate, 'day', '[]') && moment(araDateMinusOne).isSame(camStartDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

the inclusion parameters should be `[]`

```js
const obj = {
  _id: '614c2b941e06b7003024e1df',
  promotedtitles: [{ title: '1' }, { title: '2' }],
  startdate: '2021-09-04T00:00:00.000Z',
  enddate: '2021-09-04T00:00:00.000Z'
};

const camStartDate = moment(obj.startdate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2021-09-04
const camEndDate = moment(obj.enddate).format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2021-09-04
const araDate = moment('2021-09-05T00:00:00.000Z').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2021-09-05
const araDateMinusOne = moment('2021-09-05T00:00:00.000Z').subtract(1, 'day').format('YYYY-MM-DD'); // 2021-09-04

console.log('check', moment(araDate).isBetween(camStartDate, camEndDate, undefined, '[]')); // false which is fine.
console.log({araDateMinusOne,camStartDate, camEndDate})
console.log('another check', moment(araDateMinusOne).isBetween(camStartDate, camEndDate, undefined, '[]')); // this is consoling false, which is incorrect
//I also have tried this as well and all the variations.

console.log('another check 1', moment(araDateMinusOne).isBetween(camStartDate, camEndDate, 'day', '[)'));


console.log('default check ', moment('2016-10-30').isBetween('2016-10-30', '2016-10-30', undefined, '[]'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment.min.js" ></script>
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand the issue, But anyways, thanks for the help. I got the answer to the question and posted the same.